# approximation using floating point arithmetic

Tags: approximation, floating-point

**Let $x=2.14366$ and $y=2.14363$ and $d=x-y.$ If $d*$ is the value of d computed using $5-$digit decimal floating point arithmetic, find the relative error.**

For this question I know how to calculate the relative error, but the example gives $d^*$ as being $d^* = o.ooo1$ am unsure how this is calculated?.

Comment: x and y can be represented as 214366*10^-5 and 214363*10^-5 respectively but i cannot see how d* is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only five digits of accuracy in this computation, 
so $x$ rounds to $x^* = 2.1437$
and $y$ rounds to $y^* = 2.1436$.

Now compute $x^* - y^*.$